# How to open multiple pull requests from multiple branches without sharing commit history?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I've forked a repository **->** created a branch A **->** made commits and pushed changes to it **->** I then made a pull request from branch A. **->** Branch A got merged.

Now, I created branch B and pushed commits to it **->** made another pull request from branch B but this pull request show's commit history from the start of branch A. I only want to show the commits of branch B in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, If the PR for branchA is approved (**default merge strategy**), when you create a new PR for branchB, **the new PR will only show the initial commit for branchB**. As the commit I in below graph.

```
  A---B---C    branchA
 /         
D---E---F---G  master
```

After PR for branchA is approved by default merge strategy:

```
            I        branchB
           /
  A---B---C          branchA
 /         \ 
D---E---F---G---H    master
```

But the the PR for branch A is approved by **squash merge strategy**, when you create a new PR for branch B, **it will show all the history of branchA and branchB** since branchA is not really merged into master branch. Show as below graph, commit A,B,C and I will show in the new PR for branchB:

```
            I       branchB
           /
  A---B---C         branchA
 /          
D---E---F---G---H’  master
```

If you don’t want the new PR shows the history about branchA, you can rebase branchB (`git rebase --onto master branchA branchB`)  into master and create PR to merge branchB into master.

```
      A---B---C      branchA
     /          
D---E---F---G---H’   master
                \
                 I’  branchB
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like you created branch B starting from wherever you finished on branch A. If you only have one commit you want to save, then the easiest way to fix this might be a cherry-pick.

First, save the old branch `B`:

```
git branch -m B oldB
```

Then, switch to master:

```
git checkout master
```

Update your local master branch:

```
git pull --ff-only
```

Create a new branch `B` from the current master:

```
git checkout -b B
```

Cherry-pick your one commit from `oldB`:

```
git cherry-pick oldB
```

Continue with pushing and making a pull request and so on.

Note that if you have more than one commit on `oldB`, then you'll have to either do multiple cherry-picks, or a rebase (which can do a whole sequence of commits at once).